# VMWare Workstation configure network adaptor to be 'Intel Networking'

Tags: virtualization, vmware-workstation

I am trying to create a Windows VM with VMWare Workstation that has requirement to "Use an Intel networking adaptor and not 'Virtio'" I am putting this in quote as this is one of the requirement listed, not cmming from me and I can not say why it is needed.

But I can not find where and how to configure the network adaptor type with VMWare Workstation.

The more I read about this the more I understand that Intel network adaptor is the default for VMWare, but I can not say for sure.

Does someone has info on how to do this?

Comment: Is there a good reason for this requirement?

Comment: I have zero control over the requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit the .vmx file directly.

Set `ethernet0.virtualDev` to the value `e1000` to get an Intel E1000 network adapter.

```
ethernet0.virtualDev = "e1000"
```